# SmartSVN: PROPFIND of'/repo': 405 Method no allowed

Tags: svn, smartsvn

I'm relatively new to svn and I changed URL domain some days ago, so http://svn.domain_old.com/ is now http://svn.domain_new.com/. I configured new domain in server configuration. All repos are under http://svn.domain_new.com/.

When I trying to checkout repos I get the following error message in SmartSVN: PROPFIND of'/repo': 405 Method no allowed.

Do I change anything else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it the same server but just using a different URL, or is it a different machine? Either way, it sounds like either permissions or the configuration may have changed, could that be the case?

Comment: Thanks orbrey. Just using a different URL. The problem was solved, if I'm not mistaken I reconfigured and then downloaded again all repositories in SmartSVN, not a permissions problem.